# DBCC CHECKDB on Stretch enabled databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am exploring the SQL 2016 Stretch database features.  Just wondering when we execute DBCC CHECKDB command on stretch enabled database, then does it verify the remote copy of the database also?

I tried to run this command on a stretch enabled database under below mention two scenarios

1. where Azure connectivity is present
2. I restored the database so that the connectivity to Azure has been broken.

I wondered to see that there is no error in DBCC command in both the above mentioned scenarios.

I didn't find any MSDN article on DBCC for Stretch database. please provide information on DBCC usage on Stretch DB's.

Answer (score 3):

DBCC CHECKDB is not pushed to the remote DB for Stretch. There are already processes in place that do the equivalent of physical_only as part of the Azure operations so it would be burning additional CPU and storage for redundant work. The storage consumption will run up additional charges for sure though probably not a huge amount. Compute might run up additional charges depending on whether you need to bump the performance level to support the operation without affecting other workload.

Suggest filing a request on https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ to explicit document the recommended practice when it comes to SQL services in Azure (Stretch, DB and DW).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But did Microsoft documented somewhere saying that DBCC will run on local copy of stretch database only.  Is there any API which can be called using SQL SMO to do the remote DBCC check also, if required.



~Ashish

Comment: Not documented, hence the connect suggestion/bug filing. :-) If you want, you can connect directly to the database in Azure to run the DBCC CHECKDB command.